# Stop the procedure when the population of agents have the same variable in Netlogo

Tags: aggregate-functions, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to stop my simulation when most of the population of agents have the same own variable value but I really don´t know ho to do it. Here is my code for the creation and the procedure of my model:

```
 breed [birds bird]   
 birds-own [high]

  to setup
 create-turtles birds
  [
  set color blue
   set shape "circle 2"
  set xcor (-40 + random 25 )
  set ycor  (-40 + random 12)] 
end

   to go 
   ask birds
    [
   let Si4  [high] of one-of birds in-radius 1
   let conc (( 4 * Si4) + ( 2 * Ai4 ) )
   set high conc
   ]  
   end
```

I try to modulate the "high" variable using different values for the operations but I need to stop the simulation when at least 70-80% of the population of birds have the same value of "high" . I tried to use the command "modes"and "max" like this:

```
   if max modes [high] of cells > 55 [stop]
```

but this stops the simulation even if 1 bird have that value not if most of the population has it so, any suggestions to do this properly?

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this:

```
let mode  (modes [high] of turtles)

foreach mode [
  if (count turtles with [high = ?] >= (count turtles * 0.7)) [stop]
]
```

where first i define the list `mode` wich is the list with the most common elements in the turtle-own `high`, then for each of them I check if the number of turtles with that `high` is greater or equal than the 70% of the total number of the turtles.

If any of the elements of the list `mode` satisfy this condition, stop the simulation.

Comment: Great answer! But since, by definition, each mode has the same count, you don't need `foreach`. You can just check the first of them: `if count turtles with [ high = first modes [ high ] of turtles ] > count turtles * 0.7 [ stop ]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you're absolutely right, I didn't think about that!